# Dual boot ubuntu on Dell windows 10 laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, dell, windows-10

I use a DELL Inspiron 5584 laptop running on Windows 10 and it has UEFI.What procedure should I follow to dual boot ubuntu alongside without loosing the HDD data.

Comment: While you can install in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode, better to install in UEFI mode. Then you can dual boot from grub menu. Only use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk. Make sure UEFI Secure Boot is off, and in Windows make sure fast start up is off.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all the answers [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot). Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows is not really complicated. Comment in that answer (or send me a private message if it's possible on that forum??) if you need further help.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Ok thanks , I'm pretty new on this forum so I'll take your advice :)

Comment: Your welcome, just want to prevent your post from being deleted, just one more thing, AskUbuntu is not a forum, it is a Q&A site :)

Answer (score 0):

- Download and setup a USB drive that runs Ubuntu 16.04
- Reboot PC then enter BIOS and disable UEFI enabling "legacy" to avoid messing with your Windows 10 bootloader (just let UEFI stay Windows 10)
- Boot into the USB select "Try Ubuntu"
- Run GParted and select the right most partition and shrink it making room at the end of the disk. This avoids Windodws not understanding where it's located.
- Leave the space you want Ubuntu to use Unallocated and exit GParted
- Run the Ubuntu installer
- Select "Use Free Space" when installing Ubuntu

Ubuntu will detect Windows 10 and put it into the GRUB bootloader, which will be installed into the free space you created. When you want to use Windows go to your BIOS and flip it back to UEFI boot instead of "legacy" and Windows 10 will show its bootloader.